# Google Map object moves when zoom out, kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

When I zoom out my map, the object that has my current location moves, heres is the animated code, please help me.

If you need more of my app , tell me please.

```
package com.spartons.driverapp.helper

import android.os.Handler
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.spartons.driverapp.interfaces.LatLngInterpolator

class MarkerAnimationHelper {

fun animateMarkerToGB(marker: Marker, finalPosition:                                              LatLng,latLngInterpolator: LatLngInterpolator) {
    val startPosition = marker.position
    val handler = Handler()
    val start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
    val interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    val durationInMs = 2000f
    handler.post(object : Runnable {
        var elapsed: Long = 0
        var t: Float = 0.toFloat()
        var v: Float = 0.toFloat()
        override fun run() {
            // Calculate progress using interpolator
            elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start
            t = elapsed / durationInMs
            v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t)
            marker.position = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v,startPosition,                                     finalPosition)
            // Repeat till progress is complete.
            if (t < 1) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What was your expectation?

Comment: The code posted is moving a marker; I don't see any zoom changes.  Are you zooming with UI control or programmatically?  What calls 'animateMarkerToGB'.

Comment: @Andy can I send you my proyect ?and you’ll see that when you make zoom out on the app, the object that I have starts to move to another place.

Comment: @JeroenHeier can I send you my project and you’ll see when you zoom out, the object starts to move